# How to link to a controller in another area with tag helper in ASP.NET 5.0 and MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on this project where I need an area for administrators.
I have the routing working so if I manually enter the url I can get to the controller and index page with this: "http://localhost:8000/Admin/Admin", but how do I link to it using tag helpers (or actionLink) from the original home controller and index page?

What I have tried (which has not worked) is:

```
<a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index">Admin</a>  
<a asp-route="areaRoute"asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index">Admin</a>
```

I'm pretty new to this so I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I have no idea and I have not seen any example of this on the web.

I have followed the same map structure as this example (step 1): http://timjames.me/blog/2014/12/13/mvc-areas-with-vnext/
But I have "Admin" instead of "MyArea".

This is my Controller in the Admin area:

```
namespace projectName.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
[Area("Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

This is my routing:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{

 routes.MapRoute(
 name: "areaRoute",
 template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
 defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" });

 routes.MapRoute(
 name: "Default",
 emplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
 defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });

 });
```

Comment: However your template is still template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}", and area is still required there and with route you don't need controller and action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the area in the `routeValues` parameter:

```
var adminUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Admin", new { Area = "Admin" });
// or render link directly:
@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Admin, "Index", "Admin",  new { Area = "Admin" }, null)
```

routeValues is also the place to set any additional parameters required by the action, like ids.

Comment: what does "Resources.Admin" contain?

Comment: This is just a string used as the link name, taken from the Resources file. http://stvault.net/post/using-resource-files-in-asp-net-mvc-project Equivalent to writing `@Html.ActionLink("SomeLinkName", "Index", "Admin",  new { Area = "Admin" }, null)`